# How to apply both table-cell and text-overflow to same div

Tags: javascript, css

In a div, I am trying to use display:table-cell and text-overflow: ellipsis together as I want the text to grow vertically which happens by using table-cell, but when I use table-cell, overflow property does not work.
I think I should make 2 divs and apply table-cell to one and overflow to another. But this also does not seem to have affect.
Any clues?

Thanks,
KK

Please have a look at
http://jsfiddle.net/KK123/qLY6K/2/

```
.parentclass {
  position: absolute;
top: 110px;
left: 165px;
width: 470px;
height: 260px;
text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: table;
```

}

```
.childclass {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 240px;
max-height: 240px;
```

}

```
td.childclass2 {
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I am trying to apply a class to div inside a table-cell.This class is getting applies. Any clues why this is happening like this?

Comment: Do you have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or some sample code to show? I'm not sure what you mean by "text to grow vertically."

Comment: You're on the right track. That's exactly how it's done. However... seeing your code could help us help you.

Comment: Please check http://jsfiddle.net/KK123/qLY6K/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KK123/qLY6K/2/

Comment: So, as my fiddle would suggest I am trying to add a div inside a table cell and apply class to the div to enforce my overflow property. But somehow the inner class(div) is not getting applied. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.